# After method with inline function returns, add to array, isn't working

Tags: php

I'm new here on Stack, so please tell me if i do something wrong on my post!

I'm trying to create a array with SSH commands that get's executed.

I've got a method with inline-function(as you can see in my code) that returns the variable $total_space as the result.

Now what i'm trying to do, is when returning the variable, it should add the data to the commands array, bu it doesn't seem to work.
I've been nodding my head for almost two hours, and still can't figure it out.

I've tried to use array_push, but it's just returns the key with empty value.

My code:

```
$commands = array();

        SSH::run('df -h --output=size --total | awk \'END {print $1}\'', function ($total_space) {
            global $commands;
            return $commands['total_space'] = $total_space;
        } );

        print_r($commands);
```

I've expected the result to output a key-pair value, with total_space as key, and the return as value. But it only shows an empty array.

Hope somebody can help me out,

Kind regards

Comment: Maybe you should do `$commands['total_space'] = SSH::run(..., function($total_space) { return $total_space; });` ? I do not really think I understood your problem correctly.

Comment: Depends on what `SSH::run()` does with the callback, does `SSH::run()` return something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure `$commands` is in global scope and not in some class definition or something.  You could likely avoid using `global` in this case, and use `use` like this:

```
$commands = array();

        SSH::run('df -h --output=size --total | awk \'END {print $1}\'', function ($total_space) use (&$commands) {
            return $commands['total_space'] = $total_space;
        } );

        print_r($commands);
```

Also- are you sure that the inner anonymous function will execute before you try to print it?